# return accList wrong due it's return type is string but the accList is Object type

Tags: types, return

Here is my code:

```
private List<String> convertIdHmToNoAkaun(List<String> noAkaunList) {

    List<AkaunCukai> accList = new ArrayList<>();

    // loop
    for (String each : noAkaunList) {

        // identify id hakmilik
        if (!CukaiUtil.noAkaunCukaiValidator(each)) {

            // if id hakmilik -> query acc cukai to get no acc by idhkmlk
            accList.add(getCukaiTanahManager().findAkaunCukaiByNoAkaunOrIdHakmilik(each, noHakmilik));
        }

    }

    return accList;

}
```

My issue is that `return acclistt` is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `accList` is a `List<AkaunCukai>` type, but your method needs to return a `List<String>` type.

To fix this you can just change the return type to `List<AkaunCukai>` instead of `List<String>`. So replace the first line of your code above with this line:

```
private List<AkaunCukai> convertIdHmToNoAkaun(List<String> noAkaunList) {
```